# SQLite Full Text Search: PHRASE query with AND operation

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, operation, phrase

I create a phrase query in FTS like this :

```
 COLUMN_NAME MATCH '"a* b*"'
```

This query is OK.

Now, I want to create a query which include a phrase query with `AND` operation like this:

`TABLE_NAME MATCH 'COLUMN1_NAME:"a* b*" AND COLUMN2_NAME:c'`

This query returns error.

Comment: Have you compile your SQLite for the standard or enhanced query syntax?

Comment: There is no solution for this?

Comment: There is no answer for my question?